# How acess a type inside a object (REDUX in Angular)

Tags: angular, redux

When I try to acess action.payload inside a object show this error: "',' expected", in VSCODE.
But, when I try to acess inside a [array] works fine.

```
export function userReducer(
  state: IState = initialState,
  action: UserActions.Types
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActions.LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: {
          ...state.profile,
          action.payload // <------------------ does't work
        }
      };
    case UserActions.LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: [
          ...state.profile,
          action.payload // <------------------ work
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Why this hapens? How I could fix?

Thanks.

Comment: I founded the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599994/react-redux-unexpected-token-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts of an object are `key:value`.

In your example, you are trying to use the `action.payload` without specifying a key of the object

**Try this**

```
profile: {
          ...state.profile,
          ...action.payload
        }
```

**or this**

```
profile: {
          ...state.profile,
          payload: action.payload
        }
```

It works fine in the array because it's different nature. Meaning that in the array you do not have to specify a `key:value`. You have just to add items in the array like `['an_item', 1, {foo:bar}]`

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
payload: action.payload
```

inside object.